Ubuntu 23.10 - Plugging in the USB connector of an HDMI KVM switch leads to problems
I'm currently trying to set up some Raspberry Pis, mini PCs and stuff like that so that they are easy to maintain.
So I installed a monitor and bought this KVM HDMI Switch and a USB keyboard and mouse (one dongle for both components).
My setup is easy to describe:
Mini PC and Raspberry Pi are each connected to the KVM switch with the KVM cable (which has a USB port as well as HDMI). The switch has the dongle plugged in and is connected to the monitor with an HDMI cable.
When I try to switch between the two connected devices, the Raspberry Pi, shown below (1), works perfectly, but the mini PC, shown below (2), does not.
The behavior is as follows:
Starting with (1) works as expected and the monitor displays the device. The keyboard and mouse also do what they are supposed to do. But when I now want to switch to (2), the screen stays black and says that no signal is being received. So it goes into sleep mode after a few seconds.
At first I thought the switch was faulty, but after unplugging the USB part of the KVM cable (HDMI was still connected), (2) suddenly sends a signal, the monitor turns on and everything is fine. Plugging the USB part of the cable back in then allows me to operate the keyboard and mouse.
But switching back to (1) and then back to (2) does not work. Same behavior as before. Only removing the USB part results in an incoming signal for the switch. But as I said, after the signal arrives via HDMI after removing the USB part, I plug the USB part back in and everything works fine.
Does anyone have any idea why this problem is occurring?
If you need information that I should read out with terminal commands, please let me know. I'm not completely new to the Linux world, but I'm not familiar with the commands that might be needed here :)
So far I have come across the following approaches:

Enable Virtualisation in BIOS
Enable Virtualisation in BIOS 2
Change logind.conf

But I'm not sure about changing values without knowing what the effects might be.
Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated, thank you all!

Have you tried doing something else other than unplugging the USB dongle to see if that "wakes up" the Ubuntu instance on the mini PC? Other than that I think you should maybe try and 1. Switch from #1 to #2 2. Unplug the HDMI cord from the switch and plug it directly into the monitor. If that works, I'm afraid it probably boils down to the switch misbehaving / not polling the USB / HDMI signal from #2.
